# I want to host wordpress website in Google Cloud. Will my existing G suite mails work as usual?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, gmail, google-apps, google-workspace

We already have G Suite business emails associated with our domains. We added google MX records in our existing cpanel. It works smoothly. Now i want to host same wordpress website in Google Cloud. Will my G suite mails work as usual ? Do i need to change any mx records or any email settings in google cloud ?

Answer (score 1):

MX records point to google gmail servers and tied to your domain and it shouldn't have anything to do with your servers IP address.

If you want to change your servers, you should update your DNS records with new IP address.